# Magento 2 Multistore is not working with multi domain

Tags: magento2, multistore, htaccess

I am facing issue while creating multi store in magento 2. I have added 2 store abc and xyz, each points to different domain.

I have added suggested code from different sites.

In index.php I added following code

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
 case 'dev.abc.com':
        $mageRunCode='abc';
        $mageRunType='store';
        break;
  case 'dev.xyz.com':
        $mageRunCode='xyz';
        $mageRunType='store';
        break;
}
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = $mageRunCode;

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = $mageRunType;
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
```

In .htaccess file I added

```
SetEnvIf Host dev.abc.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=abc
SetEnvIf Host dev.abc.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store

SetEnvIf Host dev.xyz.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=xyz
SetEnvIf Host dev.xyz.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

Base url is also set for both store correctly in store configuration.

Now the problem is xyz store with dev.xyz.com is working fine however when i switch to abc store using store switcher its always redirect to xyz store dev.xyz.com

Please suggest me any solution. Is this store switcher issue or issue with multi domain, and how I will fix this issue.

Comment: Your htaccess parameters will always be overwritten by the PHP code. Did you try doing a var_dump on `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to see what it returns? Also are the $mageRunCode and $mageRunType variables defined before the switch? You may end up with empty variables that will always replace the htaccess values, therefor pointing you to the default storeview

Comment: var_dum on $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] return dev.xyz.com and  $mageRunCode and $mageRunType variables are not defined before switch, they return NULL before switch.

Comment: I have the same issue but there is little bit requirement difference i.e in my case I need to load the "Store" which is configured with the same website so I tried with the below solution in `index.php` $params = $_SERVER; $customstore = array( 'm.mobiledomain.co'=>'mobilestore'// storecode ); if(isset($customstore[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']])){ $code = $customstore[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']]; } $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = isset($code) ? $code : ''; $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store'; $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::creat

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 13):

I had the very same problem with MAGENTO 2.1.7 . After reading thousands (literally) of blogs, tutorials and websites I figured it out by sticking a few lines of code.

1 : Do not touch the .HTACCESS file. There's nothing to modify in there.

2 : Open INDEX.PHP and replace the following code

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

by this code :

```
$params = $_SERVER;

switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {

        case 'Domain1.com':
        case 'www.Domain1.com':
             $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'Website_code1';
                         $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
        break;


        case 'Domain2.com':
        case 'www.Domain2.com':
             $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'Website_code2';
                         $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
        break;
    }

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

There's 4 things to replace in the above code.

1. domain1.com and www.domain1.com = Your domain name for the first store (Should be the BASE store).
2. Website_code1 = Website code for the first store.
3. domain2.com and www.domain2.com = Your domain name for the second store
4. Website_code2 = Website code for the second store.

Comment: I can confirm the above solution also works for Magento 2.1.10 Commerce Edition.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, tried this solutions but they are at least misleading. The solution is a lot more simple and can be solved with the backend of magento2 and changes to the apache2 config files.

1. Dont't touch the .htaccess file as long as you have access to the virtual host config files of apache2. The .htacces file could be overwritten by any magento2 update.

   2. Add the following to the apache2 config files:

      ```
      SetEnv MAGE_MODE "developer" # or any other mode
      # "website" or "store" no other values are allowed
      # see: (1)
      SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"
      # The store or website code from the backend
      # Stores -> Settings -> All Stores -> (Code: xxx)
      SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "xxx" 
      # needs apache2 module (might work without this option)
      RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
      ```
   3. Make sure to set the right ServerName and ServerAlias in the apache2 config files
   4. Set the base in the backend Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Store -> Web -> Base URLs and Base URLs (Secure)

This should be sufficient.

(1) https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html

Answer (score -1):

Got the issue, just replace store code with "store view code"

```
$params = $_SERVER;

$customstore = array(
'm.mobiledomain.co'=>'mobilestoreview'// storeviewcode
);
if(isset($customstore[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']])){
$code = $customstore[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']];
}

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = isset($code) ? $code : '';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');

$bootstrap->run($app);

reindex, clear cache, run in another browser
```

Answer (score -1):

Got the issue, just replace store code with "store view code"

```
$params = $_SERVER;

$customstore = array( 'm.mobiledomain.co'=>'mobilestoreview'// storeviewcode ); if(isset($customstore[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']])){ $code = $customstore[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']]; }

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = isset($code) ? $code : ''; $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params); $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');

$bootstrap->run($app);

reindex, clear cache, run in another browser
```