# Magento 2 problem with multiple websites and multiple stores exist side by side

Tags: multistore, magento2.2.6, multi-website

My Magento version is 2.2.6. In our shop, we need multiple websites and stores both. The store level is working fine, but there is a problem when visiting website level link. It gets always redirect to the default website. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Below is my nginx/vhost conf:

[image: This is set as default website in admin panel]

[image: This is another store,It's working fine]

[image]

When visiting store level domain "thirdview.magento2.com", it is working fine, but when visiting the website level domain "test4website.magento2.com", it always redirects to "my.magento.com"--the default domain.

In addition, all domain were worked properly when I set the "test4website.magento2.com" as the default website，why is that? Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had similar problem on store setup we were working on. It was just one problem install. I was going to type up a reply but spotted that someone has also experienced similar problem in earlier version of magento.

Take a look at this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/183980/70343

Although in the end we just edited index.php

Didn't bother with setting codes in nginx

It's not a great answer but sometimes we just need to get the job out the door right?

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: Ran to same problem on 2.4.5-p1.   Setting up 5 multi websites, 4 kept redirecting to the first site with 1st virtualhost file in nginx/sites-available.

The solution above works but not the best solution.

Multi Store Instruction for nginx from Adobe is not working (at least in my case)