# Multiple Websites ( Separate Domains) on single Magento Instance (Problem: New Domain , routing to first website instead of new website )

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, multi-website

I am working on a Magento 2.2.7 running on Apache/Linux/Cloudways. Before I started working here, three websites were already setup to run on a single magento instance. Microbattery.com , HearingAidBatteryShop.com, and cochlearbatteries.com. I am now trying to add a third site using the magento backend. I created the website, store and storeview for hearing-aid-batteries.com and its pointed to our servers. I modified the rewrites in the .htaccess file of my magento directory but hearing-aid-batteries.com is redirecting to microbattery.com for some reason.

I have tried the following: `php bin/magento cache:clean` `php bin/magento cache:flush` `rm -rf var/cache/*` `php bin/magento reindexer:index`

I checked the tmp director to see if any cache files were being stored in there.

I changed the base url for hearing-aid-batteries.com to http://hearing-aid-batteries.com

All of these things still result in the same issue.

hearing-aid-batteries.com redirects to microbattery.com

**.htaccess and sitemap config**

```
SetEnvIf Host wwww\.hearing-aid-batteries\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=habaffiliate
SetEnvIf Host staging\.hearing-aid-batteries\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=habaffiliate
SetEnvIf Host www\.hearing-aid-batteries\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
setEnvIf Host staging.\hearing-aid-batteries\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^hearing-aid-batteries\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=habaffiliate
SetEnvIf Host ^hearing-aid-batteries\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*hearing-aid-batteries\.com$
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /aff/sitemap.xml [NC,L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hearing-aid-batteries.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.hearing-aid-batteries.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: make sure you have correct base url, run cli comman to list websites and codes

Comment: while staging is redirected too

Comment: @MagenX , the base url is correct in magento admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the error was a simple typo. if you look at my initial post:

I typed : *SetEnvIf Host wwww.hearing-aid-batteries.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=habaffiliate*

there is an extra

> w

in the url which caused cloudways to auto redirect to the main site since there was no redirect found for the actual url : www.hearing-aid-batteries.com (with 3 w's )

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered editing index.php

Similar to what's shown in this example

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/183980/70343

It worked for us on a problem install

Comment: How will this affect the existing sites .?

Comment: That's what the domain switch statement is about

Comment: I'll try that , but its really weird that the first three sites are working but not this one . Also , these settings work on the staging server without issue